# Eclipse javadoc: The type package-info is already defined

Tags: eclipse, javadoc, m2eclipse

OS: Windows 7 x64

Eclipse Platform: 3.7.2.M20120208

m2e: 1.0.200.20111228-1245

Have similar problem as in this [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=252555).
There is a bunch of `package-info.java` files in `/src` and `/test` folders, so they have same package. Eclipse show error:

```
"The type **package-info** is already defined"
```

I can delete `package-info.java` files either in `/test` or `/src` to avoid problem indication. But this workaround is not very comfort since I am using SCM and need to delete this files all time after update.
Same for **Eclipse Platform 4.2.0.I20120608-1400**

Comment: change the package name is test maybe?

Comment: I dont want do any change in project files. I want to fix this on eclipse side instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a few options to solve this:

1. Move away from package-info.java files, and replace them with package.html files.
2. Only have package-info.java files in the src/ tree, as the same-named packages in the test/ tree will "overlap" the src/ tree.
3. Generate javadoc separately for the src/ and test/ trees, as they are probably for different audiences.

Answer (score 19):

You can do this -->

Go to Build path -> configure build path -->

in Source tab -->

select the package (in which you have these problematic package-info.java file)
for eg. project-name/src/test/java

click on exclude -> and in exclusion pattern add "**/package-info.java"

this should solve the problem, as plainly you are asking eclipse to exclude these files, and thus you wouldn't have to delete those files and solving your SCM related issues

Answer (score 2):

If you use maven and m2e for interaction between eclipse and maven. There is a quite clean solution: add a profile to pom.xml that is activated only by m2e and prevents compilation of package-info.java in the test-compile phase. Here a sample :

```
 <profile>
       <id>m2e</id><!--This profile is activated when eclipse interacts with maven (using m2e).-->
           <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>m2e.version</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
           <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <!--eclipse do not support duplicated package-info.java, in both src and test.-->
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                              <id>default-testCompile</id>
                              <phase>test-compile</phase>
                              <configuration>
                                <testExcludes>
                                  <exclude>**/package-info.java</exclude>
                                </testExcludes>
                              </configuration> 
                              <goals>
                                <goal>testCompile</goal>
                              </goals>
                            </execution>                  
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
        </build>
</profile>
```